# ESLint Parsing error: Unexpected token in module.exports

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint

I am using eslint v3.0.1 with vim syntastic. For some reason I am unable to make any changes to config which removes this error

```
config/routes.js|16 col 16 error| Parsing error: Unexpected token routes [javascript/eslint]
```

in

```
var routes = (
  <Router>
    <Route path='/' component={Main}>
    </Route>
  </Router>
);

module.exports routes;
```

I am using a very generic .eslintrc right now

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line is incorrect, you need to write `module.exports = routes`.